# What do mount --slave and --rslave option do?

Tags: mount

A manpage of mount(8) said that "A slave mount receives propagation from it's master, but not vice versa", but I don't understand, what does this mean. Especially what " propagation " is and where I can read about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check kernel documentation on [shared subtrees](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/sharedsubtree.txt) for more information.

Short version:

With shared mountpoints you basically create mirror mountpoints where everything you mount in the first one gets automatically mounted in the second one. E.g. if you mount a device to `/mnt/a` it will also be mounted to `/tmp/a` (this the *propagation* part). With *shared* mountpoints this works both ways (both from `/mnt` to `/tmp` and `/tmp` to `/mnt`), but with *slave* mountpoint this works only from master to slave so if `/tmp` is slave and you mount a device to `/tmp/b` it won't be propagated to `/mnt`.